# Cannot convert from container to MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition<container>

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)   
        {
            CallMain(args).Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async Task CallMain(string[] args)
        {
```

This is the generic code I have done. After inserting some data into MongoDB

Thus, I would like to ask what are these errors? Or have I done anything wrong? The database is in an external database.

Comment: *has errors*: what errors?

Comment: Cannot convert from container to MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition<container>

Comment: @PatrickHofman  Cannot convert from container to MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition<container> is the error message

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to get all containers, call it this way:

```
collection.Find(c=>true);
```

if you want to filter your data, you could do it with expression argument, as:

```
collection.Find(c=>c.Node == "container1");
```

Answer (score 0):

you should using MongoDB.Driver

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).